# Castle ILazyComponentLoader not Intercepted

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a `ILazyComponentLoader` that registers any type on demand. My container also has an `IModelInterceptorsSelector`. When I resolve an unknown type, the `ILazyComponentLoader` is invoked correctly and then the `IModelInterceptorsSelector` is also invoked and returns the correct interceptors, but the resulting instance (which is indeed created successfully) is never intercepted. I've verified at runtime that the actual instance of the `ILazyComponentLoader` registered type is of type MyTypeProxy (in other words Castle is correctly creating a Proxy sub-class for me).

Other pre-created registrations that go through the same `IModelInterceptorsSelector` are intercepted correctly.

Any idea how I can figure out why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, being dumb, method was not virtual, please ignore.

Comment: it's encouraged on stackoverflow that you "answer yourself" and accept your own answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, being dumb, method was not virtual, please ignore